# Can't install material-ui/core for React.js project using npm

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui

I can not solve this problem while installing Material UI core or icon. Can you please help me with solution what is going on here in this error message?

```
Unrecognized token in source text.
At line:1 char:7
+ npm i  <<<< @material-ui/core
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContain 
   sErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnrecognizedToken
```

Thanks,
**Susmoy Debnath**

Comment: Can you share the command that you're running that's causing this error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have solved the problem using: npm install "@material-ui/core"